# Multiple monitors as cloned desktop windows

Tags: x11, nvidia, multi-monitor, monitors, workspaces

I am running Fedora 16 using an Nvidia card with 2 monitors. I have the monitors set up as 2 separate displays (in that I can move a window from monitor to monitor). One monitor is mounted in a different area than the main monitor (for a display used in an experiment). The question is, can the 2nd monitor's display be shown as a small window (or in a 2nd workspace) in the main monitor so that we see what is being displayed without walking over to the 2nd monitor?

Comment: *If* you only needed static content, some [PDF presenter mode tool as mentioned on `tex.SE` could help](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21777/is-there-a-nice-solution-to-get-a-presenter-mode-for-latex-presentations)  (but I doubt the antecedent is true).  Good question, btw, I'd be interested in a general solution, too.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, and you get a fun infinity effect as a bonus!

You need to set up a VNC server on your machine, and then open a VNC viewer on the same machine which you connect to yourself.

I'd suggest opening the VNC client as "View Only", or else moving the mouse pointer over window causes serious confusion, but you'll be able to see the other screen.

I don't use Fedora, but Ubuntu comes with "Desktop Sharing" and "Remote Desktop Client" installed as standard, and those do the job with no extra downloads, so I imagine Fedora can do this too.